# DynamoDB JSON or Standard JSON?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My old project has data in `Standard JSON` format in `MySQL`.

For my completely new project in `JS` (`Node.js`) and `DynamoDB`, about the data in `Standard JSON` format:

- Is it advisable to convert it to `DynamoDB JSON`?
- What advantages does `DynamoDB JSON` have over `Standard JSON`?
- Will it be easier to parse the data?
- Or does it integrate more with other AWS services like `AppSync` with `GraphQL`?
- Or is it enough to handle it as a **string**?
- Is there something I didn't consider?

**Standard JSON**

```
{ updated_at: 146548180, uuid: 'foo', status: 'new' }
```

**DynamoDB JSON**

```
{"updated_at":{"N":"146548180"},"uuid":{"S":"foo"},"status":{"S":"new"}}
```

Comment: The node aws sdk also provides a "document client" I think it's called, and I'm sure there are equivalents for other languages, which makes dynamodb data a little easier to work with. Based on your example, you would get `{"updated_at":146548180,"uuid":"foo","status":"new"}` rather than that annoying dynamo structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main benefit of the DynamoDB JSON is that you explicitly set the datatype, which is useful for the internal representation DynamoDB uses, aside from that I don't see any of them. I'm also not aware of any other AWS service that uses the same DynamoDB-JSON flavor.

In my experience, DynamoDB-JSON is just more annoying to work with, because of the additional data conversions it requires.

I prefer to use regular JSON in combination with a [JSON-schema](https://json-schema.org/) in order to enforce data types and format.

> - Or is it enough to handle it as a string?

That may be advantageous in some use cases, but if you use the DynamoDB-JSON structures, you're able to set additional indexes on the fields and even create attribute-level permissions if you require that.